# How to recursively parse data out of an e-mail using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

So I get e-mails every day with information in them. Unfortunately, for some reason, the data is sent in the body of the e-mail, and not as an attachment. Fine then. I'm using Excel to scrape Outlook, using VBA.

```
Sub mytry()
Dim olapp As Object
Dim olmapi As Object
Dim olmail As Object
Dim olitem As Object
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim olattach As Object
Dim str As String
Dim TextWeNeedToParse as String

Const num As Integer = 6
Const path As String = "C:\HP\"
Const emailpath As String = "C:\Dell\"
Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6

Set olp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olmapi = olp.getnamespace("MAPI")
Set olmail = olmapi.getdefaultfolder(num)

If olmail.items.restrict("[ReceivedTime]>=""&MacroDate&12:00am&""").Count = 0 Then


    Else

        For Each olitem In olmail.items.restrict("[ReceivedTime]>=""&MacroDate&12:00am&""")

            TextWeNeedToParse = olitem.body

            'Recursive text parsing here

        Next olitem

End If
```

Ok, so this code snippet should get me the entire body of the text into a string. Now we can pass the string around, and manipulate it.

A sample of the text I'm dealing with:

```
WAL +300bp  QTY
(M) FCTR    SECURITY    CPN ASK 1mPSA   TYPE
0.77    1.15    458 0.04    GNR 2012-61 CA  2.00    99-16   217 SEQ
1.39    2.26    120 0.76    GNR 2005-13 AE  5.00    102-24  223 SUP
1.40    18.16   45  0.65    GNR 2015-157 NH 2.50    95-16   215 EXCH,+
1.50    21.56   25  0.94    GNR 2017-103 HD 3.00    98-08   375 PAC-2
```

So there are a few different ways I can see myself tackling this, but I don't quite know all of the pieces.

1) I could try counting how many carriage returns exist, and doing a loop. Then "counting" spaces to figure out where everything is. Not quite sure how well it would work.

2) I could regex out the unique ID in the middle, and if I can figure out how to regex the nth instance (a major point where I'm stuck), I could also use that to regex out the numbers - for example, line one would be the 1-5 instance of straight numbers/decimals together surrounded by spaces, and the first instance of number-number-dash-number-number.

Sample Regex Code that I'd throw through it:

```
Function regex(strInput As String, matchPattern As String, Optional ByVal outputPattern As String = "$0") As Variant
    Dim inputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outReplaceRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim inputMatches As Object, replaceMatches As Object, replaceMatch As Object
    Dim replaceNumber As Integer

    With inputRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = matchPattern
    End With
    With outputRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\$(\d+)"
    End With
    With outReplaceRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With

    Set inputMatches = inputRegexObj.Execute(strInput)
    If inputMatches.Count = 0 Then
        regex = False
    Else
        Set replaceMatches = outputRegexObj.Execute(outputPattern)
        For Each replaceMatch In replaceMatches
            replaceNumber = replaceMatch.SubMatches(0)
            outReplaceRegexObj.Pattern = "\$" & replaceNumber

            If replaceNumber = 0 Then
                outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).Value)
            Else
                If replaceNumber > inputMatches(0).SubMatches.Count Then
                    'regex = "A to high $ tag found. Largest allowed is $" & inputMatches(0).SubMatches.Count & "."
                    regex = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).SubMatches(replaceNumber - 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        regex = outputPattern
    End If
End Function
```

3) I could try some of the methods above, but use recursion. My recursion is fairly weak.

So once I have the text string extracted, I imagine I'd need something like:

```
Sub QuickExample(Dim Cusip as String, Dim PriceStr as variant, Dim SpreadStr as variant) 
Dim ws as WorkSheet
Set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Results")
LastRow = ws.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws.cells(Lastrow,1).value2 = Cusip
ws.cells(Lastrow,2).value2 = PriceStr
ws.cells(Lastrow,3).value2 = SpreadStr

End Sub
```

And lastly:

```
Sub ParsingDate(EmailText as String)
Dim CarriageReturns As Long
CarriageReturns  = Len(EmailText) - Len(Replace(EmailText, Chr(10), ""))


For i = 1 to CarriageReturns
 'Parse out the data for the ith row, return it to the function above

Next i



End Sub
```

It's the actual act of parsing which I'm struggling a bit with - how do I properly get the nth result, and only the nth result? How do I make sure it keeps working even if some extra spaces or lines get added? Is there a way to just use regex, and "look" around the nth finding of a given expression? Is it doable to make this without a lot of recursion?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure your post shows the exact pattern of your text to parse (edit the unsatisfactory result of SO maul) and give more details about how you need to parse the string

Comment: Try posting it as picture but keep the data as well so it can be copy/paste

Comment: Fixed it. So it turns out it copys and pastes nicely into Excel - now I just need to figure out how to copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

```
WAL +300bp  QTY
(M) FCTR    SECURITY    CPN ASK 1mPSA   TYPE
0.77    1.15    458 0.04    GNR 2012-61 CA  2.00    99-16   217 SEQ
1.39    2.26    120 0.76    GNR 2005-13 AE  5.00    102-24  223 SUP
1.40    18.16   45  0.65    GNR 2015-157 NH 2.50    95-16   215 EXCH,+
1.50    21.56   25  0.94    GNR 2017-103 HD 3.00    98-08   375 PAC-2
```

This seems like a pretty well formatted table. Perhaps pop each line into an array using `Split()` and then each field into an array, again using `split()`:

```
Sub dump()

    arrLine = Split(TextWeNeedToParse, Chr(10))

    For Each Line In arrLine
        For Each field In Split(Line, " ")
            Debug.Print field
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

That's super short and runs quick. You are just an if statement and counter (or regex test) away from getting the exact items you want.

Testing/counting may be easier if you remove multiple spaces so the `split()` puts each element in it's proper place. You could employee a loop to remove multiple spaces before running this:

Fully implemented it might be something like:

```
<your code to get the bod>

'remove multiple spaces from string for parsing
Do While InStr(1, TextWeNeedToParse, "  ")
    TextWeNeedToParse= Replace(TextWeNeedToParse, "  ", " ")
Loop

'Get each line into an array element
arrLine = Split(TextWeNeedToParse, Chr(10))

'Loop through the array
For Each Line In arrLine        

    'dump fields to an array
    arrFields = Split(Line, " ")

    'and spit out a particular element (your "unique id" is element 5)
    If UBound(arrFields) >= 5 Then Debug.Print "unique id:"; arrFields(5)
Next
```

Comment: This looks super promising! I'm going to test it now. Edit: Gotta pass the text to the dump ffunction

Comment: Oh yea...I just created a fakey subroutine as an example. You can copypasta the innards out into your routine or functionalize or what have you. This is just one approach of many that would work here.

Comment: So, this may just be me not knowing enough about arrays, but it looks like this is currently a 1xN array, with the only split being along the space. Is there a way to make it a MxN array, splitting along both spaces, and carriage returns?

Comment: It's kind of like a multi-dimensional array, but instead we are just looping through a single-dim array (your lines) and then from that producing a second single-dim array (your fields for each line).  Take a look at that list bit of code I wrote and I think it might make the most sense for what you are after.

Comment: As for gobbling the string up into a multidimensional array... it would be ugly. Multi-dims are nice when your data is very well defined, but here we are just borrowing array's functionality for a parsing activity, so keeping it light and breezy with a `split()` and looping the elements of the array is really the best way to go here. I would avoid over-refactoring this since it will only end up creating more edge cases where the whole thing will fail.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Continuing to test and see if I can make it work